# Sliex ~2.0 difference between download and composer - e.g missing ServiceProviderInterface

Tags: composer-php, silex

If I download the [fat archive](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/get/silex_fat.tgz) linked here http://silex.sensiolabs.org/download I get a different silex to that when I composer require "~2.0" ( as instructed on the same page ) , for example, the ServiceProviderInterace does not exist in silex/src/Silex in the composer version, whereas in the fat archive it does. Looking at github the composer version matches...but I need the version with the ServiceProviderInterface...

I must be doing something wrong! advice please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silex 2.0, there was some changes and the *ServiceProviderInterface* was split in to *EventListenerProviderInterface* and *BootableProviderInterface* and were moved in the Api directory.
Here: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/changelog.html

In the fat archive you give, it's the version 1.1 of silex if you look at the composer.json file that's why you have the *ServiceProviderInterface*.

Comment: Yes thank you Knriano, looking at the composer.json in the archive it is indeed 1.1, so the issue is that the silex documentation page for download is pointing at the wrong version, it states " Download Silex version 2 " when actually its 1.1